# *Pear upgrade*, how to resolve "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted"?

Tags: php, pear, pecl

I am working on upgrading my pear installation and am running into memoryissues. I went as far as setting memory limit, still no luck. `memory_limit=4G`

`$ pear upgrade`

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /usr/local/pear/share/pear/PEAR/Registry.php on line 417`

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are normally 2 `php.ini` files. One used by your web server PHP and another for the PHP CLI

Run

```
> php --ini
```

To see where the `php.ini` file is for your PHP CLI environment and then increase the `memory_limit` in the correct file

> PS 4Gig is way over the top. It looks like you have a setting of 128meg so try increasing to 256M for starters

Comment: TIL about `php --ini`

Comment: It might be a good idea to decrease the 4G down to something more sensible in your web servers `php.ini` file.

Comment: Was performing a `pear` upgrade. Thank you.